# How to test on physical Nexus One with Google Play Services installed?

Tags: android, google-play-services, diskspace, nexus-one

Wanted to try my app on my old Google/HTC Nexus One, and since my app uses Google Play Services I had to install it. The problem is, now I only have 4.5 MB of free memory!

I have of course uninstalled what can be uninstalled, and moved what can be moved to the SD card, but still I only have 4.5 MB left. Google Play Services is taking up 90 MB - almost 50% of the internal storage!

What else can be done? Can I get Android Studio to install my app directly to the SD card? Or should I just forget about it and run an emulator?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no solution to hardware deficiencies. Run on other device or Emulator.

Comment: I think the best that you can do is to use an emulator then adjust its internal memory. As @camelCaseCoder said, that's already a limit of the physical device which has no workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**, by doing a hard reset.

Settings -> Privacy -> Factory data reset

After rebooting and logging in, I immediately turned off syncing and made sure Android Market was set to not auto update. Android Market seemed to update itself to Google Play Store in the background, and somehow Google Play Services also seems to be present on the phone without being explicitly installed via Google Play.

I now have 40 MB free space after my app is installed.